# Intersection of procedural road cause UV artifacts

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, procedural, artifacts

---

**I am working on a road generator that uses a curve to create a path and a spline parameter to generate UV.**

---

However, I have a problem with handling intersections. There appears noticeable artifacts. The only solution I could find was using a boolean to make a mask and mix another material, but this did not look good and affected the performance heavily.

---

**Is there a way to make the UV islands overlap each other instead? Or is there a method to generate a mask on intersections?**

---

Example of problem:
[image: UV artefacts on road intersections]

Geometry nodes (Blender 3.6.5):
[image: Geometry nodes (Blender 3.6.5)]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by storing UV attribute right after "Geometry Generation"